# Which config settings affect PNG optimisation in Sitecore image resizing?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I'm using Sitecore resizing to deliver PNGs based on viewport width of the visitor's device. Unfortunately, my 24 bit depth PNGs are being saved as 32 bit depth PNGs, at around double the filesize, when scaled down.

Which config settings can I use to control PNG optimisation in the resizing pipeline? Some seem to only be appropriate for JPEG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question

Sitecore image resizing uses native .NET libraries. These don't support any parameters for processing bit depth in PNGs, or specifying lossless compression algorithm. PNGs are first converted to a bitmap, resized and then saved as PNG, 32 bit. As there isn't any way to specify bit depth in .NET without incorporating a different image handling library, there are no parameters in Sitecore for it. The only solution is to import another library or module and incorporate this into the pipeline.

There are various possibilities for this, but Dianoga is available on Github, and extensible. https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga

Answer (score 1):

Cannot say for the setting, however there was an article about how to achieve that with PNG:

http://www.roundedcube.com/Blog/2013/building-the-png-optimizer-module

This optimized PNG from 32 bit to 8 bit reducing the file size significantly without a perceptible loss in quality.

Comment: Yes, it deals with optimization, but only within the Media Library itself. The issue with re-sizing is that optimisation and compression is lost when re-sizing. There are other modules that deal with lossless compression post resizing as well, such as http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/07/Transparent-media-optimization-with-Dianoga-2/ But I'm trying to find if I can somehow keep the settings of the original images, or control them during resizing.